# android - how to save user preferences with Facebook Account

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

*Facebook Integration* is a must-have for mobile apps these days, for better personalization of user experience. Every time I use an App that is connected to my Facebook account, it *remembers* my preferences for that app.

Let me illustrate my point through an example -

Suppose I am using **Flipboard** app on my device, by signing up using my Facebook account. Then, I select "*Algorithms*" and "*Virtual Reality*" as my topics of interest in the TOPICS section of the Flipboard app.
Now, if I uninstall this Flipboard application on one device, and install it on another device and sign in again using my Facebook account, it retains my topic choices (i.e. Algorithms and Virtual Reality).

I am really curious about how this works. I've tried Facebook Login examples (from the Official Facebook SDK page), but have not found any tutorials based on this "saving user data" problem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flipboard most likely stores your data (the information you allow Facebook to provide them, along with your in-app preferences) on their own servers (website). So, when you log into the app again using Facebook (or Google or some username), the app goes to the server and uses your Facebook info to look up your preferences. The key to keeping app data even after the app has been deleted or accessed from a different device is to not store the data on the device (phone, tablet, computer ...) but instead store it on a server somewhere under their username.